# How to get the List of Strings from Shared Preferences without the Brackets

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to save a List of Strings and display them in a `ListView.builder` Widget. The problem is when I get the value from the List I receive it with brackets around the value but I only need the String itself

Right now I'm getting: `[value]`
But I need to get: `value`

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PrefListViewBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const PrefListViewBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PrefListViewBuilder> createState() => _PrefListViewBuilderState();
}

class _PrefListViewBuilderState extends State<PrefListViewBuilder> {
  List stringList = [];

  setStringList() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList("key", <String>["value"]);
    setState(() {
      stringList.add(prefs.getStringList("key"));
    });
    print(stringList);
  }

  getStringList() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.getStringList("kfzs");
    print(stringList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: setStringList,
                child: const Text("Set"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: getStringList,
                child: const Text("Get"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(stringList.toString()),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: stringList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(stringList[index].toString()),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The getList will be

```dart
  stringList = prefs.getStringList("key") ?? [];
```

instead of

```dart
stringList.add(prefs.getStringList("key"));
```

Full snippet

```dart
class PrefListViewBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const PrefListViewBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PrefListViewBuilder> createState() => _PrefListViewBuilderState();
}

class _PrefListViewBuilderState extends State<PrefListViewBuilder> {
  List stringList = [];

  setStringList() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList("key", <String>["value"]);

    await getStringList();
    setState(() {
      // stringList = prefs.getStringList("key") ?? [];
    });
    print(stringList);
  }

  getStringList() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    stringList = prefs.getStringList("key") ?? [];
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: setStringList,
                child: const Text("Set"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: getStringList,
                child: const Text("Get"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(stringList.toString()),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: stringList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(stringList[index]),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```